# Polynomial Curve Fit without floating point

Tags: algebraic-curves, integer-programming, floating-point

big math dummy here hoping to get some advice. I'm working on a closed loop servo system that requires a curve fit on some feedback. The controller for this system is $16$-bit. With the help of excel and some online solvers I have a pretty good curve fit with a $5$<sup>th</sup> order polynomial ($y = ax + ax^2 + ax^3 + ax^4 + ax^5$). And I can apply this in the controller without issue using floating point arithmetic, but I'm curious if this curve fit can be implement in code without floating point, at least until the very end. The coefficients are very very small, in some cases $0.00xxxxE^{-18}$. Is it possible to perform the curve fit in some way with integer math rather than floating point until the very end? Thank you for any advice you can give : )

Comment: **Fixed-point arithmetic**, frequently employed in embedded systems, uses integers with implied scale factor(s), so the answer is "yes".

Comment: How would this work with a polynomial curve fit and be less processor intensive? My intuition would be, if starting the calculation at the 5th coefficient, to take the 0.00xxxE-18 and multiply everything by 10e23 to get me out of floating point and still have 6 decimals of precision when converting back to FP. This puts me way over 16 bits and then I would need to perform this same fixed point conversion again with the next coefficient at 0.xxe-15. How can I perform this curve fit in integer land with coefficients that range from e-18 to 0.1 in 16-bits.

Comment: This is a *programming* problem, not a math problem. For a worked example of how a curve fit (specifically, a polynomial minimax approximation) is used with fixed-point arithmetic, see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/529055/267031). If the 16-bit microcontroller has hardware floating-point support, there is no need to use fixed-point arithmetic. But typically these kind of processors do not provide floating-point support and need to emulate floating-point arithmetic in software, which is slow. In these cases fixed-point arithmetic usually is a faster alternative.